# url redirect, change it in codeigniter or change .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, codeigniter-url

i have to redirect one url to another. http://www.abc.com/realestate/ to Redirect to http://www.abc.com/businessfinder/company/4105/Property_Agent/. is it better to change on the codeigniter routes.php or the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that a URL should be redirected then there is no reason to hand the request to PHP. So, redirecting using the `.htaccess` file would be preferable.

If you have `mod_alias` installed then you can use the [`Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect 301 /realestate/ http://www.abc.com/businessfinder/company/4105/Property_Agent/
```

You can also use `mod_rewrite` to [jump between places](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) in various ways. E.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^/realestate/?$ /businessfinder/company/4105/Property_Agent/ [R=301,L]
```

---

If that is not possible then you can use CodeIgniter's [`$this->url->redirect()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) method. It will send the user to any website you like.